# How to Create an API Server Using Pandasai Library to Process CSV and Questions in JSON Format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dockerfile

I am working on a project that involves the use of the Pandasai library, which leverages the OpenAI GPT model to interpret and display data from a CSV file based on a user's question. My goal is to build an API server that allows users to:

- Upload a URL of a CSV file.
- Submit a question in a JSON body.

The server should then return a graph based on the data and the question. Here's an example of how I imagine the JSON input might look:

```
{
  "csv_url": "http://example.com/file.csv",
  "question": "Show me the average sales by month."
}
```

I've been able to use Pandasai locally to read a CSV file and generate graphs, but I'm not sure how to integrate this into an API server. Has anyone done something similar, or can point me in the right direction?

It is important to note that I want to use the railway or render service to bring the server live.